# limit point true false question

Tags: real-analysis

here is the statement,

> if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent, then set $\{a_n:n = 1,2,\ldots\}$
>   has exactly one limit point; true or false, and why?

1. I'm confused the concept of the limit point
2. I guess $1$ is only the limit point for this problem
3. can you explain the reason why this statement is false or true ?

thank you

Comment: Can you explain clearly the difference between being convergent and having a limit point? The distinction is important.

Answer (score 2):

A point $x$ is a limit point of the set $A=\{a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ if and only if every open nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $A$ different from $x$. If $a_n=\frac1n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, for instance, then $A=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$; every open interval around $0$ contains some member of $A$ (and that member is certainly different from $0$, since $0\notin A$, so $0$ is a limit point of $A$. You should convince yourself that if $x$ is any non-zero real number, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap A$ either is empty or contains only the point $x$ itself; this shows that $0$ is the only limit point of $A$. Of course it’s also the limit of the sequence $\left\langle\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$.

In general it’s true that if $A$ is infinite, meaning that the sequence has infinitely many distinct terms, then the limit of the sequence is the unique limit point of $A$. However, what if $a_n=3$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z^+$? The sequence $\langle 3,3,3,\ldots\rangle$ is certainly convergent, with limit $3$, but the set $A=\{3\}$ has no limit points at all. So is the statement true, or is it false?

I don’t know where you got $1$ in your second comment: there’s nothing in the statement of the problem that would make $1$ a limit point of the set.

Comment: thank you all

I'm just little bit confused with the limit point(so hard to get a concept....)

A={1/n:n∈Z+};

I understand that 0 contains cluster points of the value of A not include 0

so its limit point.(is it right)?

but how about you choose any point between 0< r < 1 , is r going to be include the cluster point of A, is r also going to be a limit point?

Comment: @Jake: Whoa! $0$ **is** a limit point of $A$; it doesn’t ‘contain’ anything. As I said, $0$ is the **only** limit point of that set $A$. If $r=\frac23$, for instance, $\left(\frac12,1\right)$ is an open nbhd of $r$ that contains no point of $A$.

Comment: bottom guy said that " an=1 for all n, then the set {an:n∈N} has no limit point as any open set containing 1 contains only 1." is this correct?

Comment: im kind of get the concept , do u have any other good question? and i want to see the other problem too. about limit point

Comment: @Jake: Yes, Anupam’s answer is correct; I have no idea why it was downvoted.

Comment: @Jake: If you search the site for `limit point` and `accumulation point`, you’ll find a lot of questions involving them; some of those questions would be suitable for you to look at. (Some of them would not, since they involve more advanced concepts as well.)

Comment: @Jake: I think now my answer will be clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $a_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$, then the set $\{a_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ has only one limit point, $0$. But if $a_n=1$ for all $n$, then the set $\{a_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ has no limit point as any open set containing $1$ contains only member $1$ of the set .

Answer (score 0):

A convergent sequence has at least one limit point.
Suppose it has 2 limit points, it means that it has two convergent sub-sequence each converges to one of each of the two points. Since a sequence converge iff every sub-sequence converge to that point and the limit of a sequence is unique, these 2 points are the same.